# Why all values in array after loop have same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why all values on return are the same `(16)["F", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and on `console.log(color)` I am getting 16 different hex colors :S

```js
 let color = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    let colors = [];
    
    for (let a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
      let x = 0;
    
      switch (a) {
        case 10:
          x = "A";
          break;
        case 11:
          x = "B";
          break;
        case 12:
          x = "C";
          break;
        case 13:
          x = "D";
          break;
        case 14:
          x = "E";
          break;
        case 15:
          x = "F";
          break;
        default:
          x = a;
      }
    
      color[0] = x;
      console.log(color);
      colors.push(color);
    }
    
    console.log(colors);
```

Comment: Works fine, what exactly are you expecting?

Comment: `color[0] = x;` is the culprit if I understand your problem.

Comment: `colors.push(color);` does not push a copy of the array. It pushes the same array reference each time

Comment: I am expecting to get array of first 16 hex colors. `[[0,0,0,0,0,0], [1, 0,0,0,0,0], [2,0,0,0,0,0] etc... ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are copy by reference, not values. Make a shallow copy in the `push()` using `...`, since it's one dimensional:

```js
let color = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let colors = [];

for (let a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
  let x = 0;

  switch (a) {
    case 10:
      x = "A";
      break;
    case 11:
      x = "B";
      break;
    case 12:
      x = "C";
      break;
    case 13:
      x = "D";
      break;
    case 14:
      x = "E";
      break;
    case 15:
      x = "F";
      break;
    default:
      x = a;
  }

  color[0] = x;
  console.log(color);
  colors.push([...color]);
}

console.log(colors);
```

Hope this is what you're looking for...

[image: console]